# Dynamicly loading js files (during runtime)

Tags: javascript

I have been able to implant the function to load the js files, but my problem is that it seems that I can only access my variables not my functions (in the object that I load). anyone got any ideas on why this is?

Comment: Not without seeing your code...

Answer (score 1):

You can load one JS file during runtime which will load other JS files
Suppose you have one js file say "Default.js" in this file just write following line.
It will automatically load "FileToLoad.js" file.
You can add as many lines as shown below to load more & more files-
e.g. document.write("");
document.write("");
document.write("");

Comment: Thankyou for your awnser, but im not sure how this will help me during runtime?